# how to control return variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, function

i want to clarify how to control  returning of variables from function in matlab,for exmaple let us consider this code

```
function [x y z]=percentage(a)
 n=length(a);
  maximum=0;
  minimum=0;
   subst=0;
 minus=0;
 plus=0;
 minus_perc=0;
 plus_perc=0;
  for i=1:1:n
      if a(i)>0
          plus=plus+1;
      else
          minus=minus+1;
      end
end
      minuc_perc=minus/n;
      plus_perc=plus/n;
                 maximum=max(minus_perc,plus_perc);
                  minimum=min(minus_perc,plus_perc);
                  subst=maximum-minimum;
                  x=plus_perc;
                  y=minus_perc;
                  z=subst*100;
                  if plus_perc>minus_perc 
                      disp('among the successful people,relevant propession was choosen by');
                      disp(z)
                      disp('% people');
                  else
                         disp('among the successful people,irrelevant propession was choosen by');
                         disp(z);
                         disp('% people');
                  end

     end
```

what i want to return is `plus_proc`,`min_proc` and `subst`,but when i run following command,get result like this

```
[c d e]=percentage(a)
among the successful people,relevant propession was choosen by
   58.3333

% people

c =

    0.5833


d =

     0


e =

   58.3333
```

so i think something is wrong,array is like this

```
a =

     1    -1     1     1    -1     1    -1    -1     1     1     1    -1
```

so ones again,i want to return `plus_proc`,`minus_proc`,and `subst`

Comment: i found my mistake,instead of minus_proc,there was minuc_proc,sorry ones again.if you like answer and i will upvote and accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return a variable in matlab you just assign into one of the specified return parameters. For example: to return the number five I would use:

```
function [foo] = gimmeFive()
    foo = 5;
end
```

Your code is not giving you the right answer because you have a typo:

```
minuc_perc=minus/n;
```

should be

```
minus_perc=minus/n;
```

You could greatly simplify the function by taking advantage of the `find` function, like so: 
Find the indeces of any element of a > 0, count them.

```
plus = length(find(a > 0)); 
plus_perc = plus ./ length(a);
```

Or if you want to cut even more out: 
a > 0 gives us a vector of 0 and 1, so sum up the 1's

```
plus = sum(a > 0);
plus_perc = plus ./ length(a);
```